# How to implement the following animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to ask  how to implement the following number animation?I hope you can help me, thank you!

[image]

can use facebook pop to achieve it?

```
POPSpringAnimation *springAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerBounds];
springAnimation.springSpeed         = 0;
springAnimation.springBounciness    = 20;
if (self.testView.frame.size.width == 100) {
    springAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
} else {
    springAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
}
[self.testView.layer pop_addAnimation:springAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate and show some code?

Comment: You can use spring animation to change scale. That's basically all. No need for `PopSpring`, there are native spring animations on `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have have a look at animateKeyFrames. Here is a sample code that can help you understand.

You could try initially setting the label to a large size that you find good. And then

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:duration delay:delay options:0 animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:frameDuration animations:^{
        //decrease view size to a really small size by changing its frame of using CGAffineTransform
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:frameDuration animations:^{
        //increase view size again to make it larger again to an appropriate size
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

Tinker around with the values to make the animation as you please.